# PL SQL Group By Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables T1 and T2. 
T1 has an ID column that is generated as a sequence.
It also has two columns first name and Last name.

The table T2 is connected to table T1 via the ID column (referential).

T2 table has a salary column, that is revised every few years.

I want to get all the first name, last name, salary , and salary date if the salary has changed.

I am not able to get this information using the ID.
A second ID is generated for the same FN and LN pair if the employee comes up for review.

For Example :-

```
ID   FN    LN
1    John  Doe
2    John  Doe

ID   SALARY  DATE     
1    $1       2015     
2    $2       2018
```

I am trying something like this

```
SELECT T.FN ||'  '|| T.LN AS NAME, COUNT(*) AS CT, 
S.SALARY, S.DATE
SALARYTABLE S, EMP T
WHERE S.ID=T.ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
GROUP BY (T.FN ||'  '|| T.LN);
```

I have solved this by using a Java program. I have to store all the ID's and loop through all the records and check if the FN and LN matches and then extract the Date and Salary. This is inefficient and I want to do it within PL/SQL.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your data model is kind of wrong; you shouldn't rely on distinguishing people on their names. What if yet another "John Doe" gets employed?

Anyway: would something like this do?

- CTEs `T1` and `T2` simulate your tables. I added some more rows, just to *make sure* that the following query doesn't fail too obviously
- `INTER` CTE joins those two tables and calculates employee's previous salary (using the `LAG` function)
- the final query select rows (from `INTER`) whose current and previous salary are different

As you already have those tables, you'd use lines 16 onwards.

```
SQL> with
  2    t1 (id, fn, ln) as
  3      (select 1, 'John', 'Doe' from dual union all
  4       select 2, 'John', 'Doe' from dual union all
  5       select 3, 'John', 'Doe' from dual union all
  6       select 5, 'Billy', 'Jean' from dual union all
  7       select 6, 'Billy', 'Jean' from dual
  8      ),
  9    t2 (id, salary, c_date) as
 10      (select 1, 1, 2015 from dual union all
 11       select 2, 2, 2018 from dual union all
 12       select 3, 2, 2019 from dual union all
 13       select 5, 3, 2016 from dual union all
 14       select 6, 3, 2017 from dual
 15      ),
 16  inter as
 17    (select
 18       t1.id, t1.fn, t1.ln,
 19       t2.id, t2.salary, t2.c_date,
 20       lag(t2.salary) over (partition by t1.fn, t1.ln
 21                            order by c_date) prev_salary
 22     from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 23    )
 24  select i.fn, i.ln, i.salary, i.c_date
 25  from inter i
 26  where i.salary <> nvl(i.prev_salary, i.salary)
 27  order by i.ln, i.c_date;

FN    LN       SALARY     C_DATE
----- ---- ---------- ----------
John  Doe           2       2018

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your SQL it looks fine as is. I am not clear if I should be starting ... from
WITH T1(COL1,COL2) .... so on, there are too many columns in the production table, I am not sure how I would use this with existing tables, if you can please give me a hint I will try it out immediately.
Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, you'd use lines 16 onwards. You already have T1 and T2 tables; I don't, so I used CTE so that I wouldn't have to create them. Furthermore, I don't know which columns you have (or don't have); are they important for this case? If so, you'll have to include them into the query, somehow.

Comment: (select
      t1.id, t1.fn, t1.ln,
      t2.id, t2.salary, t2.c_date,
      lag(t2.salary) over (partition by t1.fn, t1.ln
                           order by c_date) prev_salary
    from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
   )
 select i.fn, i.ln, i.salary, i.c_date
 from inter i
 where i.salary <> nvl(i.prev_salary, i.salary)
 order by i.ln, i.c_date;
When I use the above query, there is an error after the initial SELECT, right before the second SELECT as I am not aliasing for that I. I am still digesting the query as I dont understand it. LAG is clear, understanding the PARTITION.

Comment: SELECT you posted in a comment is part of the INTER CTE; it should still be a CTE, otherwise it won't work (or, alternatively, move it to a subquery (inline view)). PARTITION in LAG means that you have to "group" data, somehow - as there's no other information, I used *first and last name*.

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it. I used your hint to find the solution.
I tried both creating a TEMP table and doing a COUNT(*) and a HAVING > 1 clause. But your solution was the best, using WITH ( SELECT ... return all rows ) , alias the output and SELECT using partion by.